# How to remove a curtain rail fitting?

Tags: curtain-rail, fixings

I am trying to remove a current curtain rail and it’s fitting. However once I remove the initial pole and fitting stay I am left with a stud for which there is no apparent attachment method and a plate which seems to have no movement. [image: picture of remaining wall fixture]Any ideas how to remove this with minimal damage? Adding a picture of how it looks following comments to show closeness to wall.  [image: picture of wall where fitting has tried to be removed]

Comment: Jiggle and try to turn it. Either the rod will come off or the base plate will

Answer (score 2):

The plate is a cover that can be removed, revealing the screws that hold the fitting to the wall.

Some fittings that look like this have a slot or small hole on the rim. You must press a small screwdriver or awl into the hole, releasing an internal catch.

Usually, though, there is no slot, and the cover is held by a spring action. You simply pry it straight off with a butterknife or small screwdriver.

It can be difficult to do this without damaging the wall. Place a scrap of thin plywood, or a flat tool like a trowel or handsaw, between your prying tool and the wall.

Comment: Less commonly there might even be a small setscrew in a hole in the rim holding it on.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, have tried twisting and prying unfortunately with no results. Any other ideas would be earnestly received!

Answer (score 1):

In the end tried to use pliers to twist the sticky out bit and it finally gave a little and I was able to remove the cover plate. Thanks all for your suggestions!